# Replacing FWER corrections with binomial tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, familywise-error

Say I have $m$ hypotheses to test and I'd like to test them using classical hypothesis tests (i.e. with $p$ values) as part of some simultaneous inference at a confidence level of $\alpha$.

Rather than using a familywise error correction on the p-values resulting from each test, why is it not common practice to instead treat the occurrence of $p < \alpha$ as a bernoulli trial, and then run a binomial test on the number of $p$ values that are sufficiently low?

In other words, if my $p$ values from 8 tests come out to be:

`.5, .3, .2, .3, .5, .6, .02, .01`

and I want to know if $p$ is likely less than say $\alpha = .05$, can I instead look at the results like this:

`0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1`

where the number of occurrences of $p < \alpha$ (where there's a 1) should have an expected value of $\alpha \cdot m$ under the null hypothesis?  The probability of $p < \alpha$ occurring could then be tested using a binomial test where evidence against this probability being low would mean that the original null hypothesis should be rejected (i.e. low p-values occur frequently).

Assuming the probability of a rejection (i.e. where $p < \alpha$) occurring in the binomial test is $p_r$, that the overall $p$ value is $p_{final}$, and that there are $x$ p-values from the original tests that where less than $\alpha$, the test would be:

$$H_0: p_r \leq \alpha,$$
$$H_1: p_r > \alpha,$$
$$p_{final} = \sum_{i=x}^{m}{{m \choose i} \alpha^i (1-\alpha)^{m-i}}$$

Is that not a valid way to run multiple hypothesis tests?

Comment: And that is different than the Sidak correction how? (See page 68 from Holm, S. (1979). [A simple sequentially rejective multiple test procedure](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&num=100&ie=UTF-8&q=%22A+simple+sequentially+rejective+multiple+test+procedure%22). *Scandinavian Journal of Statistics*, 6(65-70):1979.)

Comment: Hm well I don't pay for JSTOR so I can't see that paper, but Sidak seems similar -- though not the same as an exact binomial test.  Can you explain why they're equivalent?